# How to output file name inside system(git log) command in ruby script?

Tags: ruby, git, git-log

The problem I encounter is that I don't manage to put the name of the file inside the below screen output inside git log using pretty format flag.

An extract of my code is the following:

```
filename = File.basename file
system('git log --pretty=format:"%cd: (here I want the filename)"')
```

presented as sample.c for example.

I tried `#{filename}` but is interpreted as a string from the compiler and the result is the same as the input.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is interpreting it as a string because single quotes do now allow string interpolation.

```
system('git log --pretty=format:"%cd: (here I want the filename)"')
```

You can change this to use double quotes so you can take advantage of interpolation and escaping.

```
system("git log --pretty=format:\"%cd: #{filename}\"")
```

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html